# ZipFile is not declared

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, zip

I am trying to use the Zipfile class in `VB.Net`, but the library can't be found. I am testing the following example code I have found on several Internet sites:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
        Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\result.zip"
        Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I get the error "ZipFile is not declared." I understand this is new to 4.5 and have tried setting my project to both 4.5 and 4.62 without success.

I have also tried to use ZipArchive, which I've found in other searches:

```
Sub Compress(filename As String, zippedFile As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(zippedFile) Then IO.File.Delete(zippedFile)

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using archive As ZipArchive = Open(zippedFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filename, Path.GetFileName(filename), CompressionLevel.Fastest)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

ZipArchive can't be found either. Can someone tell me how to resolve the errors on one of both of these examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the ZipFile class, you have to add a reference to the **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** assembly in your project; otherwise, as you have noticed you'll get the following error message when trying to compile : `The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context.`

For more information please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. But I haven't added references to assemblies in my projects before. Could you please give me more detailed steps on how to do that in VS 2017? I checked that link and it said I needed Assembly:  System.IO.Compression.FileSystem (in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll)

Comment: Right click on references in your project and click add. Then look for that dll.